# How to automatically choose mongodb based on location?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, synchronization, replication, mean-stack

I'm creating a MEAN web project as my hobby. I have two mongoDB, one is in Japan and another one is in China. Can I configure my application to use different mongoDB based on location? For example, if the user is accessing from China, then the application should be able to choose mongoDB located in China. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is actually a much better answer to this. But sadly it is off-topic since the real answer is not a programming solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using [tag based sharding or tag aware sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/). Basically, it works like this:

1. You have a value in your documents which denotes wether this specific document belongs to your chinese or your japanese data set, eg. `location: 'CHN'` or `location: 'JPN'`
2. You set up a sharded cluster, where one shard is in a datacenter in China and the other resides in Japan.
3. You [assign tags to each shard](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/administer-shard-tags/). In your case it would make sense to tag the Chinese shard with `CHN` and the Japanese shard with `JPN`
4. Now you can configure the shards that the Japanese shard should hold all documents with `location: 'JPN'` and the Chinese shard to hold all documents to hold all documents with the `location: CHN` with assigning those values to the accordingly tagged shards:

   sh.addTagRange("database.collcetion", { location: "CHN" }, { location: "CHN" }, "CHN")
     sh.addTagRange("database.collcetion", { location: "JPN" }, { location: "JPN" }, "JPN")
5. Use location as your shard key.
6. Now, you can use a single database and the data will be automatically geographically distributed and your application's queries will always be routed to the geographically matching data center.

Comment: Oh okay. It's an off-topic question (well off-topic answer) really but I guess the damage was already done. +1

Comment: Thought a while wether I should answer it, but my approach was that it was a question by a programmer concerning himself with a problem which isn't actually his. So I answered it up to the point that the OP understands that this problem is not actually his, but his DBA's.

Comment: Agreed. Plus the question was already answered, so bit of a PITA to migrate it. I guess the only value add in here is to mention that though "shards" are possible with just two servers, it is not recommended. But then again, single servers are not really a wise choice either. Clear enough point otherwise. Let the database logic handle it and leave the code alone.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the part of your code where you are sending the data to MongoDB, since you should have opened two connection.

Open two connection, one will be MongoChina, the other MongoJapan.

When a user connect, get his ip adress, and choose where which connection use based on this.

Pseudo code:

```
var MongoChina = //Connecting to the chinese mongo server,
    MongoJapan = //Connecting to the japanese mongo server;

function isJapanese(ip) {
    //Return true if IP is in japanese ip range
    //http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/jp.html
}

function isChinese(ip) {
    //Return true if IP is in chinese ip range
    //http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/cn.html
}

on.('user_connecting', function (req, res) {
    var ip = //Extract the user ip from the request;
    if (isJapanese(ip)) {
        getDataToSendToMongo(function (data) {
            MongoJapan.send(data);
        });
    } else if (isChinese(ip)) {
        getDataToSendToMongo(function (data) {
            MongoChina.send(data);
        });
    } else {
        //Do whatever you like
    }
});
```